# Apply a Material just to the part of an object that was edited by a boolean modifier

Tags: mesh, materials, modifiers

I am want to apply a material just to the faces of an object that were edited by a boolean modifier set to subtract.

[image: A/B Materials]

**A** would be one material and **B** would be another. I am also doing this in a animation, so the subtraction object is changing on every frame.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is how it works by default - materials transfer from one object to another with boolean operations. **You just need to have material slots for all the materials used on both objects.**

So if you just add a material slot and set it to the same material as the object that you use for boolean operation has it will transfer to that area.
[image]

Comment: I wish this still worked this way. edit: Yes, still does - I missed the part where both objects need that material shared between them so that it can work.

Comment: I wish this was an option of the modifier.