# Boolean operation section cut pattern black

Tags: modifiers, 3d-view

I want to use the boolean modifier to create an architectural perspective section this requires that the faces/surfaces touching the section plane/box to be colored in black (architects would relate to this).

I don't know how to do it in using Blender, if someone could help me.

This is a similar result but the cut faces are colored in orange.

https://www.plusspec.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/PlusSpec_Villa-Savoye_Section-AA.jpg

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: I guess you'll find your answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115879/apply-a-material-just-to-the-part-of-an-object-that-was-edited-by-a-boolean-modi

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to apply the material of the cut plane to the objects you want to cut below their original materials. Here this dark brown material is applied to the cut plane as a primary material and to the box as secondary material. Then the boolean operation colors the common faces with the material of the section plane.

[image]